# Problems installing caret package

Tags: installation, r-caret

I am having problems installing package caret in order to use library caret

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
```

The installation process gives several errors (log attached) and I can't load caret library

I am working in Rstudio Version 0.99.467 and R version 3.2.1 in a Windows 7 laptop

In the installation process, it seems that rstudio install previously all the caret dependencies packages

The repository configured in Rstudio is : Repository (CRAN, CRANExtra)

What Can I do?, can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance